# Is Delphi's TADOConnection thread-safe?

Tags: delphi, thread-safety, ado, delphi-7, adoconnection

I'm writing a Delphi 7 application which needs to access the same SQL Server database from many different threads simultaneously.

Can I use a single shared TADOConnection, or must each thread create their own?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Blorgbeard, you must create, initialize and open a separate
TAdoconnection instance for each of your threads.

ADO is a COM-based technology. It uses apartment-threaded objects ,don't forget to call
CoInitialize(nil).

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
   CoInitialize(nil);
   try
     try
       // create a connection here
     except
     end;
   finally
     CoUnInitialize;
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 10):

No, it is not.  ADO is a COM-based technology.  It uses apartment-threaded objects, thus you cannot use ADO connections across thread boundaries.  Each thread need its own connection.